# loess() doesn't smooth subsequently but over pooled data

Tags: r, smoothing, loess

I have time-series of 2d obsverations that I'm trying to smooth to take out some of the observation variability. I've been applying `loess()`, but just noticed it doesn't seem to smooth as a function of time but just across the entire pooled coordinates. Am I missing something? Is there a different function I should be using?

```
df<-structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1586488380, 1586488440, 
1586488560, 1586488620, 1586488680, 1586488740, 1586488800, 1586488860, 
1586489520, 1586489580, 1586489700, 1586489820, 1586489880, 1586489940, 
1586490000, 1586490060, 1586490120, 1586490180, 1586490240, 1586490300, 
1586490360, 1586490420, 1586490480, 1586490540, 1586490600, 1586490660, 
1586490720, 1586490780, 1586490840, 1586490900, 1586490960, 1586491020, 
1586491200, 1586491260, 1586491320, 1586491380, 1586491440, 1586491500, 
1586491560, 1586491620, 1586491680, 1586491740, 1586491800, 1586491860, 
1586491920, 1586491980, 1586492040, 1586492100, 1586492160, 1586492220, 
1586492280, 1586492340, 1586492400, 1586492460, 1586492520, 1586492580, 
1586492640, 1586492700, 1586492760, 1586492820, 1586492880, 1586492940, 
1586493000, 1586493060, 1586493120, 1586493180, 1586493240, 1586493300, 
1586493360, 1586493420, 1586493480, 1586493540, 1586493600, 1586493660, 
1586493720, 1586493780, 1586493840, 1586493900, 1586493960, 1586494020, 
1586494200, 1586494260, 1586494320, 1586494380, 1586494440, 1586494500, 
1586494560, 1586494620, 1586494680, 1586494740, 1586494800, 1586494860, 
1586494920, 1586494980, 1586495040, 1586495100, 1586495160, 1586495220, 
1586495280, 1586495340, 1586495400, 1586495460, 1586495520, 1586495580, 
1586495640, 1586495700, 1586495760, 1586495820, 1586495880, 1586495940, 
1586496000, 1586496060, 1586496120, 1586496180, 1586496240, 1586496300, 
1586496360, 1586496420, 1586496480, 1586496540, 1586496600, 1586496660, 
1586496720, 1586496780, 1586496840, 1586496900, 1586496960, 1586497020, 
1586497080, 1586497140, 1586497200, 1586497260, 1586497320, 1586497380, 
1586497440, 1586497500, 1586497560, 1586497620, 1586497680, 1586497740, 
1586497800, 1586497860, 1586497920, 1586497980, 1586498040, 1586498100, 
1586498160, 1586498220, 1586498280, 1586498340), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), easting = c(740.582355718548, 740.582355718548, 
739.726374785548, 739.611045841548, 739.508690311548, 739.398269506548, 
739.278804356548, 739.627760514548, 737.913640733548, 738.088450601548, 
738.551491861548, 738.957133488548, 739.137345557548, 739.304664573548, 
739.460440784548, 739.605842807548, 739.741887116548, 739.719077482548, 
739.369420509548, 738.973489249548, 738.521335985548, 739.279305656548, 
739.993757669548, 740.085239162548, 740.172262825548, 740.255157063548, 
740.334219013548, 740.409718260548, 740.481900024548, 740.550987811548, 
740.573883125548, 740.252267406548, 739.261723439548, 738.935233921548, 
738.774921432548, 738.615895069548, 738.451107559548, 738.280235586548, 
738.493740162548, 738.717501067548, 738.925752666548, 739.120074872548, 
739.301840012548, 739.472245999548, 739.632343117548, 739.890965132548, 
740.098495936548, 740.293354354548, 740.476683179548, 740.649491986548, 
740.678160672548, 740.443560695548, 740.398855065548, 740.451032168548, 
740.467918582548, 740.160041067548, 739.819912921548, 739.641686751548, 
739.457020461548, 739.265544595548, 739.193281488548, 739.227252654548, 
738.995761471548, 738.822890745548, 738.775446949548, 738.726816309548, 
738.676941805548, 738.625762928548, 739.254178659548, 739.727445331548, 
740.019566884548, 740.129316037548, 740.255273807548, 740.442527947548, 
740.615257127548, 740.775140223548, 740.923607252548, 741.055065964548, 
741.139279130548, 740.907234314548, 739.290829342548, 739.115359714548, 
740.664354207548, 740.589899151548, 740.578913554548, 740.571708783548, 
740.568311076548, 740.568740893548, 740.527920123548, 740.358565457548, 
740.392277156548, 740.370981239548, 740.289917518548, 740.214089159548, 
740.192635592548, 740.176850935548, 740.160315351548, 740.143068630548, 
740.103174446548, 740.008327647548, 740.058271768548, 740.205384482548, 
740.211048172548, 740.150159818548, 740.122028309548, 740.230164637548, 
740.271076846548, 740.075087486548, 739.768752873548, 739.586722485548, 
739.940259334548, 740.233576255548, 740.473614136548, 740.495703912548, 
740.341935547548, 740.186820856548, 740.204435025548, 740.299218490548, 
740.318343269548, 740.238895133548, 739.999671854548, 740.062183564548, 
740.196345466548, 740.329697802548, 740.418193609548, 740.311257937548, 
740.270203214548, 740.209679752548, 740.146590442548, 740.079785501548, 
740.170176300548, 740.268945921548, 740.217498771548, 740.133923060548, 
740.117921377548, 740.177771453548, 740.140658663548, 740.080204534548, 
740.108449333548, 740.145621912548, 740.182429420548, 740.010376475548, 
739.819150336548, 739.616854492548, 739.369690457548, 739.104183601548, 
738.938020260548, 738.843359187548, 738.802644324548, 738.761524527548
), northing = c(2307.15134120986, 2307.15134120986, 2307.60836846986, 
2307.72110371186, 2307.83015111886, 2307.94605545486, 2308.06963872386, 
2307.94323643186, 2308.11539257586, 2307.98516105286, 2307.67209087786, 
2307.39795736686, 2307.27544716286, 2307.16124100486, 2307.05447137086, 
2306.95438746086, 2306.86033624586, 2306.85049579286, 2307.02449397686, 
2307.22230535086, 2307.44905018086, 2306.99878407786, 2306.57790074586, 
2306.51052483586, 2306.44607531386, 2306.38433869586, 2306.32512182186, 
2306.26824947086, 2306.21356227886, 2306.16091500786, 2306.12077142386, 
2306.17964098286, 2306.35042514386, 2306.42512419786, 2306.46180283886, 
2306.49818722086, 2306.53588972286, 2306.57498431686, 2306.47587680786, 
2306.37665531786, 2306.28431106486, 2306.19814347186, 2306.11754401386, 
2306.04198150286, 2305.97099021786, 2305.88981694586, 2305.83737042086, 
2305.78847203986, 2305.74280289286, 2305.70008126986, 2305.72436278986, 
2305.79211047386, 2305.75001607586, 2305.66373079386, 2305.59454921786, 
2305.66723079486, 2305.74826733386, 2305.75631243686, 2305.76412484986, 
2305.77169383886, 2305.76318962486, 2305.74988901286, 2305.84052390686, 
2305.91140100786, 2305.95786180686, 2306.00518488486, 2306.05340722986, 
2306.10256811686, 2305.87083530186, 2305.67745118186, 2305.55808577486, 
2305.51324056486, 2305.46177226186, 2305.38525730986, 2305.31467748186, 
2305.24934676386, 2305.18868082786, 2305.13496475486, 2305.08628958686, 
2305.07937405386, 2305.33244795286, 2305.26640414086, 2304.97847050686, 
2304.88865807586, 2304.78121096686, 2304.67333694586, 2304.56517670086, 
2304.45687199986, 2304.26299422086, 2303.81398617786, 2303.81772073686, 
2303.82576399386, 2303.82937144386, 2303.85166918186, 2303.85679798586, 
2303.85841996086, 2303.85934299186, 2303.85962745886, 2303.81418344986, 
2303.71268455886, 2303.70396413486, 2303.71187848686, 2303.71241867586, 
2303.72409686386, 2303.75626565486, 2303.81432053886, 2303.80604508386, 
2303.57280991386, 2303.21896587386, 2303.06912105986, 2303.28351126486, 
2303.45378473786, 2303.49375232686, 2303.50460433986, 2303.48302188886, 
2303.48174695086, 2303.52692291386, 2303.61686633486, 2303.41139580686, 
2303.32679365886, 2303.06984393086, 2303.15017783486, 2303.29293566086, 
2303.44528532286, 2303.48203523086, 2302.89274879786, 2302.81440275486, 
2302.73512963586, 2302.65410710886, 2302.56757728186, 2302.77320543086, 
2303.00846800486, 2303.01932301786, 2302.97477011386, 2303.03742546386, 
2303.13970331386, 2303.07628123386, 2302.97297111586, 2303.02123867886, 
2303.08476293486, 2303.14766331986, 2303.17026860886, 2303.18249014186, 
2303.19025912386, 2303.15218828686, 2303.11064943486, 2302.98849464786, 
2302.87632040886, 2302.82807292386, 2302.77934558786)), row.names = 5905:6054, class = "data.frame")
```

```
df.fitted<-loess(northing ~ easting, span = .5, data = df)

df$northing.fitted<-df.fitted$fitted

ggplot(df, aes(x=easting,y=northing)) + 
geom_path(color='orangered2') + 
geom_point(aes(y=northing.fitted))
```

[image: path and loess smooth]

So, instead of smoothing the "cluster", I'd like to use a rolling average smoothing each x/y pair as a function of time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to regress both easting and northing as functions of time to get smoother x, y values:

```r
df$numtime <- as.numeric(df$timestamp)

df.fitted.northing <-loess(northing ~ numtime, span = .5, data = df)
df.fitted.easting <- loess(easting ~ numtime, span = .5, data = df)

newdat <- data.frame(numtime = seq(min(df$numtime), max(df$numtime), len = 1000))
newdat$northing <- predict(df.fitted.northing, newdat)
newdat$easting  <- predict(df.fitted.easting, newdat)

ggplot(df, aes(easting, northing)) + 
  geom_path(aes(color = "original path"), alpha = 0.6, size = 0.5,
            arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, "inches"))) +
  geom_point(aes(color = "original path"), alpha = 0.6, size = 1) +
  geom_path(data = newdat, size = 1, aes(color = "smoothed"),
            arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, "inches"))) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_light() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("original path" = "orangered2",
                                "smoothed" = "deepskyblue4"), name = "")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense! Can you explain how you chose ```len=1000``` for numtime in newdat? I also ended up playing with ```rollapply``` for both easting and northing and I think this is actually what I - incorrectly - assumed ```loess``` was doing. I'll update my post with both versions.

Comment: @Anke you can choose any number of points to interpolate on the path. 1000 will guarantee a smooth result, but even 100 would be fine unless your final image is going to be very large. The higher the number of points, the smoother the final curve but the greater the computation / plotting time.